# Как называются слова с подковыркой типа: "искусство", "параллельный"?

Tags: удвоенные-буквы

В смысле что у них три одинаковые буквы, но в одном месте в слове их две, а в другом одна, и из-за этого сложно запомнить, как они пишутся (в каком месте сдвоенная).

Answer (score 1):

Называются они, как и все заимствованные (за редким исключением: вожжи, дрожжи) слова с удвоенными и двойными согласными, словарными. Не выделено для сего феномена какого-нито отдельного термина.

Как лопухнулся один "проффесор"-шапкокрад, думаю, напоминать не надо.

---

[**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80)

> Проффесор — Виктор Фёдорович Янукович (Завгар, ЗЭК, Хам, Дважды
>   Несудимый, Витёк Межигорский, Яйцепад, Шапкокрад, Янык, Евнухович,
>   Ханукович, Бандюкович, Януковощ, Януковий Ростовский, Яйцелов,
>   Янушеску, Янучара, Ялинкович, Підарешт, Гидрант Конституции, яЖывой,
>   Легитимный, Батон, Йолкович и т. д.) — дважды свергнутый революцией
>   легитимный бульдозер титаник украинской политики, доктор
>   шапкоснимательных и экономических наук, ректор, комсомолец, член КПСС,
>   муж Людмилы Янукович, любовник Любови Полежай, внебрачный сын
>   космонавта, ректор Института уголовных проступков, известный пацанам с
>   любого района украинский политик и лидер «РыгоАналов», любитель
>   золотых батонов, серебряный призёр чемпионата по боданию с траурными
>   венками, мастер спорта по ломанию шариковых ручек и прыжкам по пням,
>   экс-царь всея Украины.

**[Происхождение мемопрозвища](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.85.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B8.D1.89.D0.B0)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Галина, а я не помню про профессора. Это не известный анекдот про детскую передачу о тушканчиках?

Comment: А по шапкокраду слабо погуглить? ))) Там текста драгоценного много, так я его в ответ, приложением!

Comment: Здесь фотография анкеты, заполненной его рукой.  https://www.pravda.com.ua/rus/news/2004/09/22/4381275/

Comment: М_Г, спасибо! Анкету я читала в Лурке, но там нет разбора полётов в украинской мове. А тута - всё как на ладошке, мерси боку!